# Is it a bad idea to install the VMware Tools 5.1 latest on RHEL guests running on VMware ESXI 4.1?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-tools

We are planning to install a VMware Tools RPM package on 50+ virtual machines running RHEL.

- Does the version of VMware Tools matter? The standard documented method to install VMware Tools is using the perl script.
- Is it better to install a package matching the host version or just the latest version of VMware Tools?
- Does using RPM to install VMWare Tools have disadvantages?
- Do I have to do something to VMWare Tools after I update the ESX hosts to 5.1 and the virtual machine to a newer hardware version?

I wonder which one of these I should use:

- http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.1latest/rhel6/x86_64/
- http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/4.1latest/rhel6/

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a bad idea to install the VMware Tools 5.1 latest on RHEL guests
>   running on VMware ESXI 4.1?

No, they're backwardly compatible, that said try really hard to get to up 5.1 or 5.5 if you can, it's worth the effort.